# Save movie info from API to a list in my database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a movie app that searches OMDb API database and populates the search results in my app. I've taken those search results and iterated over them to create movie cards for each result.

In this movie cards, I have a button to 'Add Movie To List', which would allow the user to press it and add it to lists that are already created. The user would be able to specify which list, then add it to the database.

I'm not sure how to get that action to work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

My search.html.erb page:

```
<div class="card-deck text-center" id="card-deck"> 
  <% if @movies %>
  <% @movies.each do |m| %>
      <div class="card">
        <img src= "<%= m["Poster"] %>" alt="No poster found." class="card-img-top">

        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"><%= m["Title"] %></h5>
          <p class="card-text"><%= m["Year"] %></p>
        </div>

        <div class="card-footer">
          <div class="btn-top">
            <span class="btn-group">
              <%= button_to "Add Movie To List", class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-space' %>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

How would I route that button to a certain controller action, then use the info from the API to create a new instance of a movie, then add it to a list?

My searches_controller.rb:

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @list = List.all.select(:id, :name)
    @movie = Movie.new
  end

  def omdb
    @movie = Movie.new
    @list = List.all.select(:id, :name)
    conn = Faraday.new(:url => 'http://www.omdbapi.com')

    @resp = conn.get do |req|
      req.params['apikey'] = ENV['OMDB_API_KEY']
      req.params['s'] = params[:movie]
    end

    body = JSON.parse(@resp.body)
    if @resp.success?
      @movies = body["Search"]
    else
      @error = "There was a timeout. Please try again."
    end
    render 'index'
  end
end
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :lists, :movies
  get '/search', to: 'searches#index'
  post '/search', to: 'searches#omdb'
  root 'lists#index'
end
```

My button on my Search index.html.erb to add movie to list to bring up modal popup:

```
  <div class="btn-top">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm add-movie" movie-id="m['imdbID']" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#movielistmodal">Add Movie To List</button>
  </div>
```

And my modal body code:

```
  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= form_for @movie, method: :post, url: 'add_api_movie_to_list' do |f| %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :movie_id, { id: "movie-id" } %>
      <% @list.each do |list| %>
        <%= f.label :name, list.name %>
        <%= f.radio_button :list_ids, list.id %>
      <% end %>
      <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary btn-space btn-sm' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
```

Add API movie to database controller action:

```
  def add_api_movie_to_list
    conn = Faraday.new(:url => 'http://www.omdbapi.com')

    @resp = conn.get do |req|
      req.params['apikey'] = ENV['OMDB_API_KEY']
      req.params['i'] = params[:movie_id]
    end

    body = JSON.parse(@resp.body)
    movie_params = { title: body["Title"], genre: body["Genre"], year: body["Year"], poster: body["Poster"], plot: body["Plot"], director: body["Director"] }
    movie_params.merge(params[:movie])
    @movie = Movie.new(movie_params)
    if @movie.save
      redirect_to movie_path(@movie)
    else
      flash[:error] = "Unable to save movie. Try again."
      render 'search'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Are you maintaining any list in the database?

Comment: Yes, I have lists in the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things you've to do to achieve this functionality.

1. Add a bootstrap modal which will be containing the list of movies.
2. Bring the movie_lists in a variable as @movie_list in `def search` so that you can access it on the search.html.erb
3. You'll have to use another  OMDb API to get the details of the particular movie you'll saving in the database.
4. Creating a method which is going to hit a controller method to add movies in the list.
5. Some JQuery.

I'm assuming you already have 2 models with similar relationships:

```
Class MovieList
  has_many :movies
end

Class Movie
  belongs_to :movie_list
end
```

in your movies_controller or any other controller where you've defined `def search` method.

add this line.

```
def search
  #your pre existing code
  #add the following line
  @movie_list = MovieList.all.select(:id, :name)
end
```

in search.html.erb

add html code for modal.
in modal body add code for a form where you'll be storing the `movie_id` in the hidden field and checkboxes for selection of list.

```
<%= form_for :movie, method: :post, url: 'path_of_the_method' do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :movie_id, { id: "movie-id" } %>
  <% @movies_list.each do |item| %>
    <%= f.radio_button :movie_list_id, item.id %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

specify this route in the routes.rb

now,

for each movie in search result there's a button associated to it. Let's override it's functionality.

```
<%= button_to "Add Movie To List", class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-space add-movie', 'data-movie-id': m['id'] %>
```

**NOTE:** I'm guessing you're getting uniq `movie_id` for each movie.

JQuery:

for making it work you can define it at the end of `search.html.erb`

```
<script>
  $('.add-movie').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //Let's assume the id of the Modal (popup) is #list-modal
    $('#movie-id').val($(this).data('movie-id')); //id of the hidden field
    $('#list-modal').modal('show');
  });
</script>
```

now in controller method you've just defined for saving the form value
let's assume the method name is `create_movie` or if you're using resources you can directly write `create`

```
def create_movie
  #API to fetch details of the movie id you've passed in `params[:movie_id]`
  #movie = API call
  #select the attributes you'll be saving in the database. eg:
  hash_params = { title: movie['title'], name: movie['name'] }
  hash_params.merge(params[:movie])!
  movie = Movie.new(hash_params)
  if movie.save
    #redirect with success message
  else
    #redirect with failure message
  end
end
```

I've tried to explain in the best possible manner. :P You can get a hint with it what you'll have to do. In case you still need help, just let me know.

Comment: I'm retrieving a list of movies from the API request, and I'd like to be able to add them to the db and add them to a list. As part of the API call, it returns to me a unique movie ID. How would I take this and use it to add that movie from the API call to my database?

Comment: Look into that api documentation it will surely have an end point where it will allow you to pass this unique movie id get all the relevant details of it. So, In a controller method just hit the api with the id and save the details that you want to store in the db and then add list_id associated with that movie.

Comment: Added html code for bootstrap modal, which allows for a pop-up with the lists inside. See above. I'm not getting the imdbID from the API to transfer to the params when my button is pressed to add movie to list. Any ideas?

Comment: have you added the jquery code I provided? below the html content?

Comment: I did. It brings up the modal but nothing happens when I press the 'submit' button within the form in the modal.

Comment: Here are the params from the server log:

  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qIvgaXrOe9WKmEWwMkn0fIJHuxRzJPSEFe5NuZa/npDdtrPcZSpwhAHLZ8kqnMKujap44u5Mz84AGtQrupaOPg==", "movie_id"=>"{:id=>\"movie-id\"}", "movie"=>{"list_ids"=>"9"}, "commit"=>"Create Movie"}
No template found for MoviesController#add_api_movie_to_list, rendering head :no_content

Comment: change to this`<%= hidden_field_tag :movie_id, nil, { id: "movie-id" } %>`

Comment: Params now:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"LXmCyu3LSX8kTi5N2O3n1jbiqIvGfZ6vLm1Be6mmSPVYRNF/8i9CLq8dDDTAONEEOQ9rfVsVpeU7mdjphY9YWw==", "movie_id"=>"", "movie"=>{"list_ids"=>"9"}, "commit"=>"Create Movie"}

Comment: change to this `<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm add-movie" data-movie-id="<%= m['imdbID'] %>" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#movielistmodal">Add Movie To List</button>` you're not using ruby's <%= %> operators.

Comment: That's now passing through the literal string of m['imdbID'] but not the actual info from the API call:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"UqS2XG0aq/wAIYvIvQhHBT16LQ2W9O09ntysPqxdEgQnmeXpcv6grYtyqbGl3XHXMpfu+wuc1neLKDWsgHQCqg==", "movie_id"=>"m['imdbID']", "movie"=>{"list_ids"=>"9"}, "commit"=>"Create Movie"}

Comment: use ruby's <% %> operators.

Comment: This worked! I'll now try to use that imdbID to send another request to the API, create a new movie with those credentials, and then use the list_ids from the passed in params to add it to a list. I may have more questions, but thank you so so so much...

Comment: sure, You'll find me here! :D

Answer (score 0):

Since the movies are saved to your database, you can set up a route for a custom action on your movies, in combination with `link_to`.

An example if you have `resources :movies` defined you can do something like this  ->

In `routes.rb`

```
resources :movies do
  post '/add_to_list', action: 'add_to_list'
end
```

In `movies_controller.rb` ->

```
def add_to_list
  @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id]
  @movie.add_to_list
end
```

`add_to_list` can be defined in your `Movie` model to whatever you need to do with it.

Inside your view (`search.html.erb`) instead of `button_to`, you can use `link_to` like this ->

```
<%= link_to 'Add Movie To List', movie_add_to_list_path(m), class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-space", method: :post %>
```

This is the quick solution on your question: "*How would I route that button to a certain controller action*".

For this part -> "*Then use the info from the API to create a new instance of a movie, then add it to a list?*" I will guess a few things:

- You have some service object that is issuing queries to OMDB API through some gem
- You save enough information in your Movie model so you can issue another query to OMDB API to get the information on a specific movie (that user will click on in your list)

If this is the case, then you can create a model concern that will contain some logic to interact with OMDB service object

For example, that custom method I put above `add_to_list` can be defined in that concern.

If you need more info on how to do that, you can contact me.

Comment: I appreciate the help above, but the movies aren't saved into my database yet. I've got the movies from the API populated in my view, but I want to save them in the DB and associate them with a list. I've edited my question above to include my searches_controller and my routes.

Comment: I'll update my answer in what I think should help you. But first, I am interested in what your `@resp` variable contains. Can you debug the output of that variable and send me what it contains?
Comments do not support empty lines (I guess) so I can send you the code you need to add in order to debug but in private message.

Comment: I found a solution, check this link and open app/controllers/searches_controller.rb -> https://repl.it/@ZlatkoAlomerovi/DecisiveCornyEngine